# How to change the text of a <li> from a number to a letter on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The page loads list tags with text like this:

```
"1 some text"
"2 other text"
```

What I want is:

```
"A some text"
"B other text"
```

I'm very new to jQuery/JS so I'm having a bit of trouble knowing how to reference the object, get the text, run the function when the object is generated on a jinja for loop.

What I've thought of was getting the number which is in the `data-index` and passing it to `charAt()` using a string like this `'ABCDE'`, and then concatenating the rest of the string with the right letter based on the index.

The problem is that I don't know how to make js/jQuery do that onload(I read about this but it doesn't seem to be working yet for me) for each `<li>` as they are generated with jinja.

This is the html snipppet:

```
        {% for alternative in question.alternatives %}

        <li name="alternative_letter" onload="getLetters();" id="alternativa-{{ loop.index }}"
            data-index="{{ loop.index }}" class="list-group-item"><b>{{ loop.index }}</b> {{ alternative.get("title")}}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <div>
```

Unfortunately I haven't had any progress with JS. I tried a few things but they seemed pointless, specially since the browser debugger didn't even seem to notice the code.
Just to have something I tried:

```
    var letters = 'ABCDE';   
    if( $("li[name='alternative_letter']").text.slice(0,1)

        $(this).text(letters.charAt($(this).data('index')) + 
        $(this).text.slice(1));
    });
}
```

I expect it to run the function for each `<li>` tag generated on this page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to do this *on page load*? If you want them to be letters immediately, why not simply change the HTML directly?

Comment: Off topic but the statement I'm very new to jQuery means you are spending your time learning an outdated method of web development. jQuery was great in it's day but that day is far behind us. If you are new to JS learn a modern framework like Angular, Vue, Svelte or React. Don't waste your time learning outdated methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it's what you want:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li[name="alternative_letter"]');
items.forEach(item => {
 item.querySelector('b').innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(64 + parseInt(item.dataset['index']));
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li name="alternative_letter" data-index="1" class="list-group-item"><b>1</b>Some text 1</li>
  <li name="alternative_letter" data-index="2" class="list-group-item"><b>2</b>Some text 2</li>
  <li name="alternative_letter" data-index="3" class="list-group-item"><b>3</b>Some text 3</li>
  <li name="alternative_letter" data-index="4" class="list-group-item"><b>4</b>Some text 4</li>
  <li name="alternative_letter" data-index="5" class="list-group-item"><b>5</b>Some text 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works! Thank you!
Why doest the const execute without having to call it, though?

Comment: Constants (consts) are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the `var` statement. It's available in ES6. You can change it to `var` if you want the code works on IE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `type` attribute for `li`

> *type* can take values **1|a|A|i|I|disc|circle|square**. [More info](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_type.asp)

```html
<ul>
  <li type="A">Some text</li>
  <li type="A">Some other text</li>
  <li type="A">Some more text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer but for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: can you be a bit more clear with the issue you are facing with this solution? This is simple css, so should work ideally.