# Arbitrary values in HTML list

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm trying to make a HTML list with the following format:

```
1. Note 1
2. Note 2  
    2a. Subnote
```

This brings me to a broader problem. Is it possible to set the values before the period in a HTML list to any arbitrary string?

I've tried wrapping the list in a `<ul>` and then setting `<li value="string">`, but this has no effect.

Comment: You should possibly look at [CSS `counter()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter) and [CSS generated content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_generated_content); then come back to us with specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the text of a <li> from a number to a letter on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895365/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-li-from-a-number-to-a-letter-on-load)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing you have to use [css counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter)

```css
ul {
  list-style    : none;
  counter-reset : count_1 0;
  }
ul > li:before {
  counter-increment : count_1 1;
  content           : counter(count_1) '. ';
  }
ul ul {
  counter-reset     : count_2 0;
  }
ul ul > li:before {
  counter-increment : count_2 1;
  content           : counter(count_1) counter(count_2, lower-alpha) '. ';
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Note 1</li>
  <li>Note 2
    <ul>
      <li>Subnote x</li> 
      <li>Subnote y</li> 
      <li>Subnote z</li> 
    </ul>    
  </li>
  <li>Note 3</li>
  <li>Note 4
    <ul>
      <li>Subnote</li> 
    </ul>    
  </li>
</ul>
```

PS: I would have answered faster if you had put a minimum of html and css code… (and before David Thomas's comment)
do not forget to validate this answer, if it seems right to you, otherwise leave an explanatory comment..